# Highcharts Scatter Chart Data Point Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following current version `Highcharts` (http://www.highcharts.com) chart.  My "default" data point is blue.  Notice the two data points colored red, one toward the bottom left ("Item 1")  and the other at the top right ("Item 2").  They are as intended when not hovering.  My problem is that when hovered they do not appear the same.  Item 1 stays red whereas Item 2 turns blue.  When hovered I want them to stay red.

[image: Chart]

Item 1...

[image: Item 1]

Item 2...

[image: Item 2]

I thought that when hovering maybe there was a z-index problem but couldn't find a solution there.  I then turned to Highchart's API regarding hovering but I'm not sure how this could be a problem since I'm not setting any hover colors and one is correct and the other is not.

The data I'm passing to the chart is as follows...

```
0 Object { name=1, x=-4, y=-0.8, color="red" }
1 Object { name=2, x=9.5, y=9.5, color="red" }
2 Object { name=3, x=-1.37, y=1.64 }
3 Object { name=4, x=-0.7, y=-2.8 }
```

Your help is appreciated.  Thank you.

=== UPDATE ===
https://jsfiddle.net/edzasxg5/

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle or Plunker demo so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Created https://jsfiddle.net/edzasxg5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the 'fillColor' for the hover property, otherwise it picks up a default.

```
  { id: '1', x: -4, y: -0.8, color: 'red', marker: { states: { hover: { fillColor: 'red' } } } }, 
  { id: '2', x: 9.5, y: 9.5, color: 'red', marker: { states: { hover: { fillColor: 'red' } } } }, 
  { id: '3', x: -1.37, y: 1.64 }, 
  { id: '4', x: -0.7, y: -2.8 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/strince/edzasxg5/1/

UPDATE:
There is an even simpler solution to set 'fillColor: {}'.

```
    marker: {
      radius: 2,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true, 
          fillColor: {},
          lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)', 
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Simple enough.  Works.  Thanks very much for your effort and responsiveness.  One question though - with my original code, why did Item 1 work correctly and Item 2 did not?

Comment: Poking around the Highcharts code and issues on GitHub, looks like there is a bug filed for the problem.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1440